# Connecting my Rails Web app database to my Rails API on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, heroku

I feel like my question is partially answered through a number of other questions, but I just can't piece everything together for my case.

Basically, I'd like to build a fairly simple web app, but also be able to fairly easily build a mobile app for it down the line. From my research, the best practice would be to build a RESTful JSON API, and then use that API both for my web app and for my mobile app.

I've already gone ahead and developed authentication for my JSON API (using : http://lucatironi.net/tutorial/2015/08/23/rails_api_authentication_warden/) and I've got it up on Heroku. Now for my web app, I'm using [HTTParty](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty) to consume that API, and I'm getting the JSON back all fine and dandy. However, I'm not quite so sure what to do with the database. My first thought was that maybe I need to access the API's database via it's own API calls, but that seems incredibly complex (just the thought of having to make functions for `User.find_by_<every attribute>` makes me scared). The other thought would be to have my web app use the API app's database. However, I can't find any info on how to do that if the app is on Heroku.

So basically, I'm wondering what the best way to go about this would be. Surely there is a standard out there that every big or small web app with an API uses. I'm really surprised that something so prevalent these days is hard to find good answers for. Or am I going about this all wrong? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are add-ons in Heroku parlance.

Use `heroku addons` to get a list of the add-ons for your apps.

```
$ heroku addons -a appname

Add-on                                    Plan       Price
────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────
heroku-postgresql (relaxing-purely-8366)  hobby-dev  free 
 └─ as DATABASE
```

First you may want to remove the database attached to your front-end app:

```
heroku addons:destroy fat-samurai-1234
```

Then find the name of the database add-on attached to your API app and attach the add-on to your frontend app.

```
heroku addons:attach shining-sushi-1234 -a sushi.
```

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons#creating-an-add-on

---

As to which approach is legitimate that's a matter of discussion. Many apps today use a single page architecture where the entire app is created on the front end - in javascript. So your app just consumes your REST api. Popular frameworks for this are Ember.js, Bootstrap and Angular.

The other approach would be to to create a classic server side app - while it's possible to create an app that would consume the REST api there is a significant overhead involved so it will be more performant to connect directly to the database.

Comment: I'm not sure but attaching the database to your frontend app before the first push to heroku may stop heroku from generating a database for the app - which is a good thing.

Comment: Cool, didn't know you could do that in heroku. I'll give it a try. However, this brings up the question of how development works. Does my development db for the front end have to use the development db of my api? Is that possible, to run my api server locally, as well as my front end. Or can I somehow connect my development environment to heroku? It'd naturally be a staging version. Probably mean for another question, but if you know, that'd be great.

Comment: Depends - I usually just have enough sample data in the development database to be able to do reasonable work with CSS/HTML. Using a remote database for dev might be possible but sounds like a PITA. If you need to dev on the real data use PG backups and mirror the data to your local database.

Comment: Staging is a whole different question - but you should probably use another database and repeat the same steps for the two staging apps.

Comment: Thanks, everything seems to work. However, you got me thinking about whether I should have a database at all for my front-end (since it is in fact just a front end). I mostly thought I did since I only got back an email and token from my authentication, and I just wanted to use `User.find_by_email` to get the logged in user, but as I build my api, I'm going to have to copy over new models and the new schema every time. Seems annoying and error prone. And if I were to go the Angular route, I wouldn't have access to the database anyway. So should I even be messing with a db for my front end?

Comment: Well the major drawback of SPA's is that they require javascript. If your requirements don't call for a no-js fallback then go for it.

Comment: Instead of copying your models and shared functionality you could however place them in a gem - you can use github as the source so that you don't have to publish the gem to rubygems.org.